# Connect ArcGIS map to existing MySQL databse?

Tags: arcmap, mysql

I have an existing dataset in a MySQL database that refers to specific country codes in Rwanda. I was curious whether or not it's possible to link an ArcGIS map of Rwanda to that dataset and display the information? I scoured the internet but didn't find any clear answers...

Any advice or direction?

Comment: Depending on your version of ArcGIS you could use MySQL ODBC driver (older versions supported this).

Comment: You've tagged this with ArcGIS Online. AGOL is certainly not going to be making ODBC connections.